# Start Google Maps with structured address

Tags: android, android-maps

How do you start Google Maps (or whatever map provider is registered to take `geo` URIs), while providing as much structured address information as is available?

My application has access to the formatted address (human readable) as a single string, as well as the structured breakdown of country code, postal code, admin area, etc. Additionally, it has a name for the location (a company name or a person's name) and sometimes a latitude and longitude.

I'm using `startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, uri))`. The question is what to use for `uri` to let Google Maps provide the user the best experience. It would be nice to fill out a [android.location.Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) and have it generate a URI for me, but there seems to be no such feature. Even good documentation on the URI would be useful. All I could find is a [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5870#section-3.4), but who wants to read all that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it will ask you to choose between Google Maps or your browser, and set          address as your destination.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + address))
```

Comment: But what is `address`? I'm looking for how to provide the address in a structured form to ensure the user gets the best possible map location.

Comment: The formatted address you'll get from your application should be enough to get a good location. BUT you can also try to convert your address to latitude and longitude to use     maps?ll= instead of     maps?q=  that way you should get something really precise.